# RSS feeds for Associated Press News

Tags: rss, feeds, news-feed

I like reading news from [Associated Press](http://apnews.com), but rather than using their website I'd prefer to use RSS feeds. The problem is I can't find any RSS feeds nowhere on their website.

The only things I found using search engine was this [cryptic link](http://hosted2.ap.org/APDEFAULT/APNewsFeeds). It does have a list of feeds indeed, but they don't work properly - each post has invalid link which redirects to the [main page](http://apnews.com).

I contacted Associated Press, but they didn't reply me.

Does somebody know how to obtain a proper working RSS feed for AP? I can't believe such a huge professional news organisation wouldn't have RSS feed for their site...

Answer (score 1):

It seems that AP uses a custom XML format for their feeds. RSS is very limiting in terms of the data types that it allows and requires. (Media RSS adds a bit more in the area of media, images, etc.)

The link you found for AP's feeds has this format for feed data. Take a look at the source to understand format:

https://jsfiddle.net/grbx8ruv/

Where are you looking to use the RSS? Simply to subscribe to? Or integrate in a web application?

If looking to subscribe, see if this helps: http://smallbusiness.chron.com/rss-ap-42619.html

Comment: Just to subscribe for personal use. I use a feed reader (currently InoReader) to read the news and I like the articles from AP.

Comment: Even if RSS is limiting, what's the use of publishing an RSS feed that doesn't conform to the standard? The article you linked to, doesn't help - it only explains how to subscribe to a feed, which I know well how to do, and the links it provides are dead.

Comment: And even if they use custom format, from the structure of the feed (which you linked to in https://jsfiddle.net/grbx8ruv/) I still don't see any way to get a working URL to the article. The URL there is: 'http://hosted2.ap.org/APDEFAULT/3d281c11a96b4ad082fe88aa0db04305/Article_2018-01-10-US--Trump-Immigration/id-758fab066d8d4ad0aaaa901f31a1b0a7' is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

The lists I found in January have disappeared but here are a few I captured then, and they still work. They are not RSS though they are Atom, and that should be readable by your newsreader.

AP Top Headlines:

```
http://hosted2.ap.org/atom/APDEFAULT/3d281c11a96b4ad082fe88aa0db04305
```

AP World Stories:

```
http://hosted2.ap.org/atom/APDEFAULT/cae69a7523db45408eeb2b3a98c0c9c5
```

AP World Stories:

```
http://hosted2.ap.org/atom/APDEFAULT/386c25518f464186bf7a2ac026580ce7
```

Comment: The links in the feeds don't work - they redirect to the main page instead of to the page with article.

Comment: Well, these appear to be dead now. I have decided RSS is a dead duck. To programmatically get news from these places, use the Twitter API or just use Twitter and follow them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this PHP script: https://github.com/supahgreg/ttrss-apnews

There's also this page http://hosted.ap.org/lineups/lineups.html?SITE=AP but this morning I was having some problems with it (the css and images from the site is gone and it's loading very slow) but it was working before that.

I once emailed AP about the RSS feeds when the links started to redirect to the main page (which happened in late September of last year) and they were saying they were "shutting down" but it never actually shut down, so not sure what they are doing with them...

Comment: Why would a news portal shut down it's RSS/Atom feed? It's such an accessible way to access the site's content with no similar alternatives as far I know.

Comment: Not sure. I like the RSS feeds too though. Hope what I gave you helps.

Comment: It works, but superslow (pages load up to few minutes) and lacks the photos in articles that you can't find on apnews.com. If they decided to shut down RSS, it seems it won't work and I'll stay with reading news on Reuters, which has a flawless RSS feed. Still thanks for the help!

Comment: Yeah I know, I had to stop using the RSS feed for that. I'm currently parsing their JSON in their API to get the news.

Comment: Any update on this? I would love to subscribe via RSS or Atom.

Comment: There's not an RSS feed, but there's this: http://afs-prod.appspot.com/api/v2/feed/tag?tags=apf-usnews

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: https://rss.app/
just paste https://apnews.com/ on it and it'll turn it into a RSS feed which you can then subscribe to.